# Alinhar texto depois de escolher uma opção no select

Tags: javascript, css3, bootstrap-3

Olá,

Pessoal, preciso de um help para alinhar textos. Tenho um select com uma lista de cidades, nessa lista existem endereços, quando selecionamos uma cidade, só será mostrada informações referentes aquela cidade (Obvio rs), mas o problema é o que  texto não fica alinhado, ele fica perdido no meio da tela.

Exemplo: Selecione a cidade Barueri, o endereço aparece no canto inferior direito, quando na verdade deveria aparecer logo abaixo do select.

Obs: Se você selecionar outras cidades como São José dos campos, será listado mais de um endereço.

Print: http://prntscr.com/f376wf

Projeto: https://codepen.io/leonardop21/project/full/DQeLLD/

Código: https://codepen.io/leonardop21/project/editor/DQeLLD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode esconder os elementos que não são alvos, dessa forma:

```js
$('select[name="list_citys"]').change(filterList);

function filterList(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").parent().parent().removeClass('esconder');
  if (value == "all_city") $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").slideDown();
  else {
    $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").slideUp();

    $(".list_citys_shop ul:not([data-category*=" + value + "])").parent().addClass('esconder');
    $(".list_citys_shop ul[data-category*=" + value + "]").find(".new-citys").stop().slideDown();
  }
}
```

```css
.shop-text-h4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(221, 29, 57);
}

.list-unstyled li {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.esconder {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width:980px) {
  .col-md-3 {
    height: 135px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="stores">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img src="http://www.bluebeach.com.br/shoponline/home/lojas/BLUEBEACH-CAT.GIF" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="citys">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Cidade</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="list_citys">
              <option value="all_city">Todas</option>
              <option value="city_sp">São Paulo</option>
              <option value="city_barueri">Barueri (Tamboré)</option>
              <option value="city_campinas">Campinas</option>
              <option value="city_guaruja">Guarujá</option>
              <option value="city_santos">Santos</option>
              <option value="city_santo_andre">Santo Andre</option>
              <option value="city_sao_campo">São Bernado do Campo</option>
              <option value="city_sao_jose_campos">São José dos Campos</option>
              <option value="city_ribeirao_preto">Ribeirão Preto</option>
              <option value="city_outlet">Outlet</option>
            </select>
            <br>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="list_citys_shop new-citys">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING ANÁLIA FRANCO</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Regente Feijó, 1.739 / Piso Orquidea</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Anália Franco</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 2076-1126 / 2076-1154</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING CENTER NORTE</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Travessa Casalbuono, 120 / Praça Central</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Vila Guilherme</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 2252-2734</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING ELDORADO</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Rebouças, 3.970 / 1º Piso</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Vila Guilherme</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 2252-2734</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING FREI CANECA</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Consolação</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Vila Guilherme</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 3472-2153</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING GRANJA VIANA</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Rod. Raposo Tavares, KM23 / L2</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Granja Viana</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 4613-6773</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING IBIRAPUERA</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Ibirapuera, 3.103 / Piso Ibirapuera</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Moema</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 5536-3535></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING INTERLAGOS</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Interlagos</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Moema</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 5678-2020</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING METRÔ SANTA CRUZ</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Domingos de Morais, 2.564 / Piso L1</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Vila Clementino</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 3471-7956</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING PÁTIO PAULISTA</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Treze de Maio, 1.947 / Piso Maestro Cardim</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Bela Vista</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 3284-2020</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">RAPOSO SHOPPING</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Rod. Raposo Tavares, KM14,5 / Piso Raposo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Jardim Boa Vista</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F 11 3735-1764</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sp">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING WEST PLAZA</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Antartica, 380 / 2º Piso</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Perdizes</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Paulo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 3803-8960 / 3803-9210</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_barueri">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING TAMBORÉ</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Piracema, 669 / 1º Piso</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Tamboré</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Barueri (Tamboré)</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 4191-4881</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled position" data-category="city_campinas">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">IGUATEMI CAMPINAS</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Iguatemi, 777 / 2º Piso</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Vila Brandina</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Campinas</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 19 3727-9100</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled position" data-category="city_campinas">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">PARQUE DOM PEDRO SHOPPING</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Dr. Guilherme Campos, 500</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Santa Genebra</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Campinas</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 19 3209-0517</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_guaruja">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">SHOPPING LA PLAGE</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Mal Deodoro da Fonseca, 885</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Pitangueiras</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Guarujá</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 13 3383-2193</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_santos">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">PRAIAMAR SHOPPING</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Rua Alexandre Martins, 80 / 1º Piso</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Aparecida</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Santos</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 13 3227-6707</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_santo_andre">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">GRAND PLAZA SHOPPING</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Industrial, 600</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Jardim Santo André</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Santo André</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 4979-5098</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sao_campo">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">GOLDEN SQUARE SHOPPING</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Avenida Kennedy, 700 / 1º Piso</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Jardim do Mar</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Bernardo do Campo</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 3135-4030</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sao_jose_campos">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">CENTER VALE SHOPPING</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Deputado Benedito Matarazzo, 9403 / Piso Dutra</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Jardim Oswaldo Cruz</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São José dos Campos</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 12 3901-8270</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_sao_jose_campos">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">VALE SUL SHOPPING</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Andrômeda, 227</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Jardim Satélite</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São José dos Campos</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 12 3222-1236</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_ribeirao_preto">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">RIBEIRÃO SHOPPING</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Cel Fernando Ferreira Leite, 1.540 / Piso Mogiana</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Jardim Califórnia</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Ribeirão Preto</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 16 3911-3802</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_outlet">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">OUTLET SÃO PAULO</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Av. Nova Cantareira, 698</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Santana</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Outlet</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 2281-0011</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_outlet">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">CATARINA FASHION OUTLET</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Rod. Castelo Branco, KM 60</li>
        <li class="new-citys">São Roque</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Outlet</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 4130-4686</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-citys list-unstyled" data-category="city_outlet">
        <li>
          <h4 class="shop-text-h4 new-citys">OUTLET PREMIUM</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="new-citys">Rod. dos Bandeirantes, KM 72</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Itupeva</li>
        <li class="new-citys">Outlet</li>
        <li class="new-citys">F. 11 4496-4656</li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
</section>
```

Coloquei o código todo apenas para visualização, mas os pontos são:

**CSS:**

```
.esconder {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('select[name="list_citys"]').change(filterList);

function filterList(e) {
    var value = e.target.value;
    $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").parent().parent().removeClass('esconder');
    if (value == "all_city") $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").slideDown();
    else {
        $(".list_citys_shop .new-citys").slideUp();

        $(".list_citys_shop ul:not([data-category*=" + value + "])").parent().addClass('esconder');
        $(".list_citys_shop ul[data-category*=" + value + "]").find(".new-citys").stop().slideDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado @Lucas Costa